# Do OS-X app bundles always contain Info.plist - CFBundleExecutable?

Tags: macos, applications, plist

I wonder if OS-X app bundles always have a Info.plist - CFBundleExecutable configuration?

Thank you in advance for answers.

Comment: You are referring to 10.7, 10.8, and 10.9 from MAS or other bundles (as well)?

Comment: @AndrewU. Doesn't matter all OSX application bundles needed this - I can't remember which version of OSX needed it first

Comment: @AndrewU: I am not sure what MAS is. I am referring to version 10.7 - 10.9

Answer (score 4):

Yes see Apple's [documentation on bundle structure](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/conceptual/cfbundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW19)

An OSX Application bundle must contain an Info.plist and expects certain keys including CFBundleExecutable whose definition is

> The name of the main executable file. This is the code that is executed when the user launches your application. Xcode typically sets the value of this key automatically at build time.